# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 14; 2 is required

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm currently trying to plot my Random Forest model's Gini impurity score like so:

```
##### Calculating Gini Impurity across model features #####

feature_names = np.array(X_train.columns) # len = 191

gini_impu = rf.feature_importances_

std_gini = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in rf.estimators_],
                   axis = 0)

idx_gini = np.argsort(gini_impu)

# Plotting

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(23, 25))

ax.barh(range(len(idx_gini)),
            gini_impu[idx_gini],
            yerr = std_gini[idx_gini],
            color = "b",
            align = "center")

ax.set_title("Random Forest Feature Importance (Gini)", fontsize = 20)
ax.set_xlabel("Gini Impurity", fontsize = 15)
ax.set_yticklabels(range(len(idx_gini)), feature_names[idx_gini])
ax.tick_params(labelsize=15)
```

However, I am met by the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-4691ce5fa1c9> in <module>
     20 ax.set_title("Random Forest Feature Importance (Gini)", fontsize = 20)
     21 ax.set_xlabel("Gini Impurity", fontsize = 15)
---> 22 ax.set_yticklabels(range(len(idx_gini)), feature_names[idx_gini])

...
...

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 14; 2 is required
```

I've checked the length of each variable that I'm trying to plot and they are all the same. I'm not entirely sure what this error is telling me. I've tried to look at other examples of the same error but they are too specific. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [matplotlib `axis.set_yticklabels` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels.html), the method takes arguments `labels`, `fontdict`, `minor`. You pass 2 arguments, what seems to be position of ylabels first and y-labels themselves second.

As per the previously mentioned documentation, it warns:

> This method should only be used after fixing the tick positions using
> Axes.set_yticks. Otherwise, the labels may end up in unexpected
> positions.

So, you seem to have mistakenly combined the functionality of both methods.

What you should do is:

```
ax.set_yticks(range(len(idx_gini)))
ax.set_yticklabels(feature_names[idx_gini])
```

Comment: Ah yes, I see the error now. Thank you for not only explaining the error but also providing the correct code. @dm2